# java -Xmx512m working fine but -Xmx1024m not working, what is the difference?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a swing based application which runs as an "Exe format".  Recently I faced issue when I tried to open exe it shows *"could not create java virtual machine"*. I went through all files and found one of the ini files mentioned as below

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

I changed the maximum heap size to -Xmx512m, and then my application opened fine.

Why does my application works fine when I reduced the maximum heap size to 512m instead of 1024m?

Second question, what will happen if I keep the maximum heap as 512m and if I do multiple process in the application means will it through any error during when multiple activity is going on the application?

Please suggest what is the best maximum heap memory size to keep so that my application works fine.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit application?

Comment: application is 64 bit I verified in the compatibility mode there are gray out options and shows windows 8. Also jre is embedded with my application. This tool is mainly used for workorder management, inventory management etc. Jre is old Java 6 embedded. –

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what is your application.
If you can't start your application with 1GiB of memory, but can with 512MiB, you probably have a problem with your JDK or the embedded JRE of your application.

Conventionally, we use multiple of 2 for heap size, so if 1024 didn't work, stay on 512. It's difficult to say more without knowing what's your application, and what's the need.

For your second question, if you start multiple thread on your application, they will just share the available memory between them. Nothing should specifically happen compared to single threaded application.

***Edit:***

I founded this, who can help you understand your problem maybe
https://blog.openj9.org/2020/04/30/default-java-maximum-heap-size-is-changed-for-java-8/
It seems there is a limitation on heap size on specific jre version <= 8

> The Xmx value is 25% of the available memory with a maximum of 25 GB. However, where there is 2 GB or less of physical memory, the value set is 50% of available memory with a minimum value of 16 MB and a maximum value of 512 MB.
> For Java 8
> The Xmx value is half the available memory with a minimum of 16 MB and a maximum of 512 MB.

Comment: I replaced your uses of mo and go, which I believe are commonly used in French, with the [internationally accepted units (defined by the IEC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units), GiB and MiB

Comment: Oh thanks! True, we use it commonly in french, my bad.
We use commonly XO for X-octet (1 byte / 8 bit), and XB for X-bit

Comment: application is 64 bit I verified in the compatibility mode there are gray out options and shows windows 8. Also jre is embedded with my application. This tool is mainly used for workorder management, inventory management etc. Jre is old Java 6 embedded.

Comment: how to avoid this issue in the embedded JRE of my application.  is there any way to change the JRE to latest version

Comment: There is an separate JRE folder in the package which is Java 6

Comment: I edit my answer, i maybe founded what's your problem

Comment: The quote you added is about the default value when you don't specify any memory config, given the OP does specify a value for memory, that quote doesn't apply.